# I need API of Computer Research Center of Islamic Sciences (Quran) with translations

Tags: quran, shiism, quran-translation

I am looking for shia Quran API with translations to use in my software, are there already built in shia Quran APIs to use?

Comment: What's a shia Quran? Also that's off-topic, ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Quran translation which have a shia Translator